# how to fix PHP not fetching data from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image]

I'm working on a post sharing website and I need to collect the title of the post from my MySQL database called "mugg_website". After writing the PHP code, creating the post on the MySQL database and running it using WAMP, there is no title, that needs to appear on the homepage.

my code (mugg.php):

```
<?php
    require_once("connection.php");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>mugg. | Pradinis</title>
        <link>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>mugg.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="index.php">Pagrindinis</a>
            <a href="#">Pasiekite mus</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <?php 
                $q='SELECT `id`, `post_title` FROM `post` WHERE `status`="paskelbta"';
                $r=mysqli_query($con, $q);
                if($r){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
                            $id = $row['id'];
                            $post_title = $row['post_title'];

                            echo '<a href="?id='.$id.'">'.$post_title.'</a>';
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo 'no post';
                    }
                }else{
                    echo $q;
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(connection.php):

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mugg_website");
?>
```

Comment: `$q='SELECT ... WHERE status="paskelbta"';`  "paskelbta" ? In the screenshot you got a status "published"

Comment: what, that's odd, I remember I changed that

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mugg_website");
?>
```

to

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mugg_website");
?>
```

And also add error message in case of connection error.

```
// Check connection

    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

Comment: OOP is better than procedural and die with error is a terrible debugging practice.

Comment: There is no use of OOP so that why I suggested procedural way and for error message that is only meant for use during developing process @Dharman